# PHP SQL Update Query syntax

Tags: php, sql

I'm working on my first PHP/MySQL project, and I've gotten basic logins and INSERT queries working, but not updates.  This is my first update, which is just one row with a state and zipcode.  Is anything wrong?

```
$dbc = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$state=$_POST['state'];
$zip=$_POST['zip'];

$custnum = 0;
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET state = '$state', zip = '$zip', WHERE custnum = '$custnum'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql)
or die('Error querying database.');
```

Comment: you don't need the last comma before the "WHERE" clause

Comment: You *are* mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions, which won't work.

Comment: Also, the code you show is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Use the proper sanitation method of your library (= in this case, `mysql_real_escape_string()`), or switch to PDO and prepared statements.

Answer (score 4):

```
$sql="UPDATE {$tbl_name} SET state='{$state}', zip='{$zip}' WHERE custnum='{$custnum}'";
```

Remove the last comma before "WHERE" clause. Also, if you're just starting out it's good to put parenthesis around variables names when using double-quotes for strings. Helps you to distinguish the variables better.

Pekka is also correct in his comments, you are mixing mysql and mysqli functions. Use mysql_query() instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to get rid of the comma just before the WHERE.

Answer (score 2):

```
$suitno =mysqli_real_escape_string($ecms,$_POST['suitno']);//protecting sql injection 
$defendant=mysqli_real_escape_string($ecms,$_POST['defendant']);//protecting sql injection 
$casenature=mysqli_real_escape_string($ecms,$_POST['casenature']);//protecting sql injection 

$sql="UPDATE causelist SET suitno='{$suitno}', 
casenature='{$casenature}' WHERE suitno='{$suitno}'";
$result = mysqli_query($ecms, $sql)
or die('Error querying database.');
```

Comment: you should detail your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
    $dbc = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect"); //don't need quotes
    mysql_select_db($db_name,$dbc)or die("cannot select DB"); //added the $dbc (connection link) as a second parameter

    $state=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['state']); //Should make it safe!
    $zip=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['zip']); //Should make it safe!

    $custnum = 0;
    $sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET state = '$state', zip = '$zip' WHERE custnum = '$custnum'"; 

//removed an extra comma

    //Notice that $tbl_name isn't defined!
    u
    $result = mysql_query($sql)
    or die('Error querying database.'); //from mysqli to mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a sql syntax error:Remove the comma before WHERE

Answer (score 0):

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    //echo $name; die;
    $surname=$_POST['surname'];

```
 $upd="update table_name SET  name='$name',surname='$surname' where id=$id";
mysql_query($upd);
```

}